# Set can baudrate with ioctl or similar from C/C++

Tags: socket, iproute, ioctl

I'm currently setting the baudrate of my can0 with ip link:

/sbin/ip link set can0 up type can bitrate 250000

I'm just wondering how to do the same from within C/C++?

Comment: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/iproute2/iproute2.git/tree/ip/iplink_can.c?h=v5.4.0#n244 . Hope you can move on from there (it's probably using netlink messages).

Comment: @A.B thanks for the link I didn't think to look in iproute source.

Comment: I think a question that would require an answer to be really code oriented would fit better on SO than here. But check SO's policy about the question. It might require showing some code first. I doubt you can get an actual answer here on UL SE.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed earlier you can look into iproute2 source code which uses libnetlink. However according to the docs [libnetlink is meant for internal use, use libmnl for new programs](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/libnetlink.3.html).

Libmnl's api is slightly different so it's not a drop-in replacement, but it does the job and works in the same way. Basically you need to setup a netlink message, and then start adding nested attributes. Once your message is build, send it over to the netlink using the libmnl socket api's and you're done.

Example code for setting a link up/down:
https://github.com/pevik/libmnl/blob/60e34d339522bbad3142fa1609e4506edd33c969/examples/rtnl/rtnl-link-set.c

Note that for setting the baudrate you don't need to set the `ifi_flags`. Instead, after adding the attribute that contains the can device name (using `mnl_attr_put_str`), you need to add a nested linkinfo object using `mnl_attr_nest_start`, `mnl_attr_put_str`. Next using those same functions you also need to add the can bittiming object (`struct can_bittiming`). See [iplink_can.c](https://github.com/shemminger/iproute2/blob/9f366536edb5158343152604e82b968be46dbf26/ip/iplink_can.c#L117) for an example on what data needs to be set in this struct. You finish building the payload by calling `mnl_attr_nest_end` for both nested objects.